# SSE intrinsics to copy bytes within a register

Tags: c++, c, sse, simd, intrinsics

Assume I have four floats loaded into a register (`f0` to `f3`), as illustrated by the following pseudo code:

```
__m128 xmm1 = < f0, f1, f2, f3 >
```

Now I want to copy the first element to the other positions, so that I get a register that looks as follows:

```
__m128 xmm2 = < f0, f0, f0, f0 >
```

(`f0` is only avalable within that SSE register)

How can I archive this as efficient as possible? I know that there is a trivial naive solution (unload the first element, then use `_mm_set_ps1`), but I wonder if this can be done more efficient.

Comment: `shufps xmm1, xmm1, 0x00`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with [_mm_shuffle_ps (SHUFPS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5f0858x0(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
#include "xmmintrin.h"   // SSE

xmm2 = _mm_shuffle_ps(xmm1, xmm1, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

---

Note: depending on how you've ordered the elements in your example above it might instead need to be:

```
xmm2 = _mm_shuffle_ps(xmm1, xmm1, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 3, 3));
```

Comment: It's annoying that with AVX it requires two intrinsics/instructions to do a broadcast.

Comment: Indeed, especially given that `vbroadcastss` can broadcast across all 8 elements from a memory address (AVX) or lowest element of a 128 bit vector register (AVX2).

Comment: As already stated by @paul-r, with AVX2 this can be achieved using the intrinsic _mm_broadcastd_epi32(__m128i val); Don't know if there is a float version, but casts in this context is free